# IP address limit

Tags: domain, ipv4, dynamic-ip

I currently work in a company running a domain on 192.168.150.# dynamic Ip assignment. We seem to be running out of private Ip address allocations.

1. What is the limit?
2. How could we work around this?

The scenario we have a main site wireless network Bus-1 and a guest wireless network Bus-Guest and then a wired network for all the workstation terminals and network devices (printers).

We have a Draytek and a soft firewall as part of the setup.

Any advice?

Comment: Depending on how dynamic your user/device count is, it could be that devices that aren't connected are holding onto a DHCP lease.  Shortening your lease expire/refresh time can increase the load on your DHCP source somewhat but will help ensure that only devices that are actually connected are holding a lease.  This can be a big issue on guest networks that see lots of changing users

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using a /24 (255.255.255.0) subnet mask then the limit is 254 ip addresses usable by host systems. If you want to enlarge that address range (increase the number of host usable ip addresses) then change your subnet mask to /23 (255.255.254.0). This will double the number of host usable ip addresses.

Another solution would be to add another network and route traffic between the two networks. For instance, you could add a 192.168.151.0/24 network and route traffic between the 192.168.150.0/24 network and the 192.168.151.0/24 network.

Comment: Hi Joe, sorry we are on a /24  subnet mask. That's amazing news. I know it was probably a stupid question, but if you don't know... Ask? Right?

Comment: Right. There are no stupid questions. Well... there are some stupid questions but your question isn't stupid. ;)